# Review a List of Tables and Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal:
Display detailed information if `database A` use `database B`:s `table` and its `column`. if yes, the list will display what is the name of the `database B`:s table and column that is being used in `database A`.

Purpose:
The main purpose is to reduce the time. `Database A` has about `200 View` and `400 tables` and `database B` has about `154 View` and `165 tables` and I don't wanna review each table and view in order to locate what table and column it use from `database B`.

Problem:
I do not know how to do it?

Information:
*I'm using `SQL server 2008 R2`

Comment: Can you add some code that you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` as below to get desired results:

```
USE [database A]
GO

select
  object_name(objs.referencing_id) as objectname
  ,cols.*
from
  sys.sql_expression_dependencies objs
  outer apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ( OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objs.referencing_id) + N'.' + object_name(objs.referencing_id), N'OBJECT' ) as cols
where objs.referenced_database_name = 'database B'
```

You can refer here for more details:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315(v=sql.100).aspx